# Speed up google cache

Tags: caching, seo, meta-tags

Is there a way, a meta tag, to speed up google cache?
Because i have done some changes, dynamically, and even after a few weeks, i see only the old outdated results. I have even checked the logs and google bot is present every day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always using "noarchive" in the meta-tag for robots. This will prevent the site from being cached by Google.

Changes to the page title or description and new pages are very fast on the search results and the link to "see on Google cache" disappears.

I think it takes a week at max and people are forced to view your page and not the outdated cache version.

Like this

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noarchive,noodp" />
```

Combined with a sitemap-file it does a great job on all of my sites.

Answer (score 0):

There are no meta tags or direct ways to tell Google to re-index a page. You may be able to encourage it though:

Create an xml sitemap and submit it to Google Webmaster Tools. 
While in Google Webmaster Tools check if Google has any issues with indexing your website.
Make sure your not telling Google not to index you (robots.txt, robots meta tags)

Google has some rules on deciding how regularly it indexes pages and website. Authority, rate of change and speed may all factor in to when it will next update.